Bin packing but each ball can only go into a subset of the bins. Does this problem have a name?
Say I have a collection of balls $b_1, \dots, b_k$ and bins $B_1, \dots, B_n$.
Each ball $b_i$ is only allowed to go into a collection of specified bins $S_i \subset \{B_1, \dots, B_n\}$.
Each bin $B_i$ has a capacity $c_i$.
Can you fit all of the balls into the bins?
That is, can I assign to each ball $b_i$ a bin $B_j$ such that $B_j \in S_i$ and the total number of balls assigned to each $B_j$ is less than or equal to the capacity $c_j$ of that bin.
It's likely that this problem has been studied before - does anyone know if it has a name?
I'm mostly interested in writing an algorithm to efficiently confirm whether a packing is possible (rather than finding a solution).

See also eligibility constraint in the scheduling literature.

I think "Each bin $b_i$" should be "Each ball $b_i$"?

"finding whether a packing is possible rather than finding a solution" is known as satisfiability (SAT)

You can solve this as a transportation problem in a directed bipartite network with nodes $b_i$ with supply $1$, nodes $B_j$ with capacity $c_j$, and arcs $(b_i,B_j)$ for all $B_j\in S_i$.

Extending Rob's answer, if you're only interested in knowing whether a solution exists then you can use a result from Miguel Constantino's thesis:
Constantino, Miguel. A polyhedral approach to production planning models: start-up costs and times, upper and lower bounds on production. Diss. UCL-Université Catholique de Louvain, 1995.
The result says that a necessary and sufficient condition for a solution to the transportation problem is that for each subset of demand nodes, the sum of supply at the supply-nodes connected to those demand-nodes, exceeds the demand at those nodes.  You can write an algorithm which checks this - no need to form an optimization problem or use a solver.  In practice you do not need to check all subsets, only those which are not dominated by another (where one subset is said to dominate another if it is a strict superset and is connected to the exact same supply-nodes).  If there is a pattern to the connections between balls and buckets then you can use this, along with domination rules, to simplify the identification of which demand subsets are sufficient to check.

Maybe I'm misinterpreting, but how does this work in the case where we have, say, two supply nodes (each with a supply of 1) connected to a single demand node (say with a capacity of 1). There is no solution to this, but the criteria you gave would indicate that there is, since the sum of the supply at supply nodes (1 + 1) exceeds the demand at the demand node (1). What have I misunderstood?

I'm not sure why you are saying there's no solution. There are two solutions, corresponding to the demand being satisfied by either supply node. In terms of your original problem this is the situation with 1 ball, that can go in either bin. Choose a bin, put it in.

My apologies - you're right. For some reason I was viewing the balls as the supply and the bins as the demand, so the situation I outlined would be two balls trying to fit in a bin with capacity 1. I see now that it makes more sense to model it the other way.
